# Does prayer timetable stay same every year?

Tags: salat

Through out the year prayer times change, but is it the same every year? For example on the 04/07/15 morning prayer is xx:xx, does it stay the same next year at same day and month (04/07/16)? Given that the location is the same.

Comment: Depends wherr on the earth you're located and how many seasons occur.

Comment: Given that the location is exactly the same, let's say somewhere in London, or New York, the same exact location, would the prayer time table remain the same every year?

Comment: Yes, if you have the timetables for the entire year, then they shouldn't change much for the next year, unless the earth shifted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earth takes just under 365.25 days to orbit the sun; the calendar year was designed to approximate this, but typically only has 365 days (because whole numbers). As such, every solar year, the calendar year will get slightly more and more out of sync: This is why leap years were invented.

Since each calendar day actually occurs about six hours *earlier* in the solar cycle every year, the prayer times which are tied to direct solar position will also be slightly out-of-sync from year to year; these will *mostly* (but still not *perfectly*) sync up every *four* years, after a leap day has re-synced the calendar.

(It'll sync up even better every *four hundred* years because of how the current Gregorian leap cycle is calculated.)

The actual difference would be negligible in most cases; unlikely to exceed a minute either way. But no, you can't expect them to match up perfectly between years.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very small change in the prayer times, even when following the solar calendar. Look at the following prayer timetables for different years.

[July 2010](http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayerPrintable.php?city2=New_York&state=NY&id=3271&longi=-73.9967&lati=40.7500&country2=Usa&zipcode=&today_date_flag=2015-7-4&changeTime=16&pmethod=5&HanfiShafi=1&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=1&dayl=1&timez=-5.0&dayLight_self_change=&prayerCustomize=&lang=&fajrTwilight=0&ishaTwilight=0&ishaInterval=0&month=7&year=2010)

[July 2020](http://www.islamicfinder.org/prayerPrintable.php?city2=New_York&state=NY&id=3271&longi=-73.9967&lati=40.7500&country2=Usa&zipcode=&today_date_flag=2015-7-4&changeTime=16&pmethod=5&HanfiShafi=1&dhuhrInterval=1&maghribInterval=1&dayLight=1&dayl=1&timez=-5.0&dayLight_self_change=&prayerCustomize=&lang=&fajrTwilight=0&ishaTwilight=0&ishaInterval=0&month=7&year=2020)

Answer (score 0):

They don't change, unless you are using a lunar calendar instead.Perhaps that is why are you asking this question.

For instance Ramadhan this year started on June 17th, next year it will start 11 days earlier and therefore the timetable for the first day of Ramadhan will change while if Ramadhan was following a solar system then it would have been the same every solar year.